# Pasar valor de php a configuración de un objeto en Js

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando introducir un valor de una variable de php en la configuración de un objeto json, ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
 document.getElementById("download-pdf").addEventListener("click", function () {
             
                               table.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {

                    orientation: "landscape", //set page orientation to portrait
                    **title: <?php $dato;?>,** //add title to report
                    styles: {
                        fillColor: [000, 255, 255]
                    },
                    columnStyles: {
                        estacion: { fillColor: 255
                        , height:40 }
                    },
                    margin: { top: 60 },
                
                });
            });
```

Como podéis ver quiero asignarle a la propiedad titulo el valor de una variable en php, ¿es esto posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta poner entre comillas y aumentas el echo

```
title: "<?php echo $dato;?>",
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!